# Rails 4 - Unauthorized user can't see dependent models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed the Hartl guide and the rubyonrails.org guide to create a site. I've noticed that unauthorized users cannot see either of the dependent models that are attached to my `Article` model. The dependent models are `Comment` and `Photocup`.

It doesn't matter how I try and display them, these don't work:

```
 <%= render @article.photocups %>
 <%= render @article.comments %>
```

In the case of `Photocup`s, I have created a partial called `_gallery.html.erb`, and used:

```
 <% @photocups.each do |photocup|%>
```

The `_gallery.html.erb` partial renders along with the article itself, but an unauthorized user doesn't see the photocups.

All of the methods above work perfectly for an authorized user.

The `ArticlesController` allows index and show:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:index, :show]
```

What do I need to do so unauthorized users can see these dependent models?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: added article controller below.

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:index, :show]


   def check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1",   unchecked_value = "0")
   end

   def remove_photo 
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   @article.photo = nil
   @article.save
   redirect_to @article
   end

   def feature
   @articles = Article.all
   end



  def index
    #displays the full list of articles
   @articles = Article.all
   #if User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
   # render 'index', flash[:notice] => "Opps, need to be logged in to     do this!"
   #end

    #alt. method displays articles only created by the current user.
    #@articles = Article.where(user_id:current_user.id)
   end

   def showall
   @articles = current_user.articles
   end


  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @photocups = @article.photocups
   end

   def new
    @article = Article.new
   end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   end

   def create
    @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
   @article.author = current_user.name
    #@article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
    else
  render 'new' #, :notice => "Opps, something not quite right!" 
    end 
   end

   def update
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   if @article.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.admin?
  #update author in case of user name change
    if @article.user_id == current_user.id
      @article.author = current_user.name
    end 
  if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
    else
    render 'edit'
   end

    elsif
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "You do not have permission   to edit this resource."
    end

   end

  def destroy
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])

   if @article.user_id == current_user.id
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "Article Deleted."
   else
    redirect_to articles_path, :notice => "You do not have permission  to delete this resource."
   end
  end

   private
    def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :author, :manufacturer, :displacement, :model, :photo, :misc)
     end
    end
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to provide us full source code of your controller :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add the same *authorization skip* both in PhotocupsController and CommentsController like this:

```
class PhotocupsController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:index, :show]
 #...
end


class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:index, :show]
  #...
end
```

I think you block unauthorized users to see comments and photocups, maybe because you have added a general check for authorization in the ApplicationController?

Let me say!
bye

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work. I experiment a great deal with the filters. My application controller does indeed have 'before_action :authorize', but I'm not convinced that the problem. If it was an authorization issue, wouldn't it redirect me to the login page? It doesn't, the photos and comments simply don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It had nothing to do with authorization, it was simply db corruption. For some reason, unauthorized (non-logged in) users were being served up incorrect article ids. I figured it out by clearing the logs, then examining what happened when non-logged in VS. logged in users requested the same article. I did a db:reset, and have not been able to recreate the problem.